# Why does Visual studio slow Targo bank website?

Tags: asp.net, localhost

Using Visual Studio and Chrome I have recently started debugging a website at http://localhost:50481 in a project created with the ASP.NET empty website project template. About the same time I noticed that my desktop banking website was running very slowly. In fact the whole https://www.targobank.de/de/index.html web site runs very slowly using Chrome. All other websites are fine. In MS-Edge the targobank site runs fine (sometimes). I believe that the Visual Studio setup is somehow slowing Chrome at my German bank!

Does anybody know why this might be happening? Perhaps other users with similar VS configurations could try the website.

Here is some more detail on my VS setup. In order to use the ASP.NET empty website project template I had to install  "Additional project templates (previous ver..)" as shown below and as recommended on the excellent stackoverflow.

[image]

Use the ASP.NET empty website project template thus
[image]

and then debug my Javascript in Chrome using a website at http://localhost:50481.

Comment: Well, I would un-install vs and re-boot. I mean, you have to post a re-producable case here for others to try. I not seen any posts or suggestions on SO in year that suggest VS is going to effect other web sites. Now, if you have IIS express + VS running? Then sure, since VS is attached to the web browser process for debugging - then that should effect the browser operation. But, if not running IIS and VS? I don't think they are related, but un-installing IIS express and VS would shed more light on this issue.  So while running VS + IIS? Sure, that can well effect things, but reboot and try.

Comment: It is not really practical to uninstall VS to do banking and then reinstall it to do coding, I do both quite a lot. But I will try it as a one off experiment. Is there any way to get VS to reinstall with exactly the same workloads as I have now? Or must I take screenshots so that I can replicate my previous installation? I don't think I will be doing it today 

Comment: Did not suggest that. I stated that WHEN you un-install VS, does the problem go away. And then when you re-install VS (and are not running VS), does the problem return?

Comment: In other words, this test will verify that un-installing VS will fix this issue. If un-installing VS does not fix this issue, then we have a greater issue and problem, but worse, we determined that un-installing VS does not help! So, as noted, does a un-install of vs fix this issue? And does a install of VS make the issue return, but even when not having run or used VS?

Comment: I have uninstalled VS and IIS Express. The banking website is still slow :-( . Therefore I cannot blame VS / IIS. If I find something interesting for this site I will comment further but I suspect I will have to reset the PC. Thanks Albert D. Kallal.